# PHP create a pallet counter

Tags: php

I am trying to to create a PHP loop to take a starting int variable and increment based on the number of wigets per pallet to get the ending variable for that pallet. Then start the next pallet with 1+ the ending number from the previous pallet.  Until the total qty have been reached. I have tried several different loops but none of the get me the results.  This is the latest.  It will give me the number of pallets, but it keeps the same beginning number for each pallet.

```
for( $x = 0; $x <= $num_of_skids; $x++)
    {
    $skid_num++;
    $mfg_end_num = $mfg_begin + $per_skid - 1;
    $mfg_begin_num = $mfg_end_num + 1;
    fputs( $fp, "SKID # " . str_pad($skid_num, 2, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . " " . $cst_prefix .        $cst_begin . "-" . $cst_prefix . $cst_end . str_pad( " ", 5, " ") .  $mfg_prefix . $mfg_begin_num . "-" . $mfg_prefix . $mfg_end_num . "\r\n");
}
```

Thanks
Kenny

Comment: You might want to add `$x` here like : `$mfg_end_num = $mfg_begin + $per_skid - 1+$x;`

Comment: I assume $skid_num is initialized to 0 before the loop. What about $mfg_end_num, $mfg_begin, and $per_skid. Are they all initialized to 0 before the loop?

Comment: $skid_num and $mfg_end_num are set to 0 prior.  $mfg_begin and $per_skid are pulled from a DB.  Yes they are all initialized before the loop.

Comment: here is what i want to result to look like.

Comment: 100 - 104 / 105 - 109 / 110 - 114.  i have the starting number and the number for incrementing.  This continues until the qty has been met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do -

```
$mfg_begin_num = $mfg_begin + ($x*$per_skid); // get the 0 based start
$mfg_end_num = $mfg_begin_num + ($per_skid - 1); // subtract 1 due to 0 based loop
```

to make it

```
for( $x = 0; $x <= $num_of_skids; $x++)
    {
    $skid_num++;
    $mfg_begin_num = $mfg_begin + ($x*$per_skid);
    $mfg_end_num = $mfg_begin_num + ($per_skid - 1);
    fputs( $fp, "SKID # " . str_pad($skid_num, 2, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT) . " " . $cst_prefix .        $cst_begin . "-" . $cst_prefix . $cst_end . str_pad( " ", 5, " ") .  $mfg_prefix . $mfg_begin_num . "-" . $mfg_prefix . $mfg_end_num . "\r\n");
}
```

take a look at this at this phpFiddle example - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5wg-mx2

this outputs this -

```
SKID # 1 XXXXXX-XXXXXX X100-X104
SKID # 2 XXXXXX-XXXXXX X105-X109
SKID # 3 XXXXXX-XXXXXX X110-X114
```

Comment: This makes the $mfg_begin_num begin at 0.  I need to have the $mfg_being_num start with a predetermined number from a DB that i am pulling in to $mfg_begin variable.  When i substitute this variable in it populates the $mfg_being_num for each line  for example:  it will show 100 - 104 / 100 - 104 / 100 - 104.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I have updated my answer above. try `$mfg_begin_num = $mfg_begin + ($x*$per_skid);`